SSH error when using a private GitHub repository as a dependency in a Cloud Build project deployed to Cloud Run
I have a project on GitHub that has a private GitHub repository as one of its dependencies. I'm trying to deploy this project to Google Cloud Run using Cloud Build. I’ve added the private repository to Google, created SSH keys, and configured them in GitHub.
Here is my Cloud Build YAML file:
steps:
  - name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/git"
    entrypoint: "/bin/sh"
    args:
      - -c
      - |
        mkdir -p /root/
        mkdir -p /root/.ssh
        echo "${_GITHUB_SSH_PRIVATE_KEY}" >> /root/.ssh/id_rsa
        chmod 400 /root/.ssh/id_rsa
        echo "${_GITHUB_SSH_KEY}" >> /root/.ssh/known_hosts
    id: Set SSH Key
    volumes:
      - name: "ssh"
        path: /root/.ssh
  - name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/git"
    entrypoint: "apt-get"
    args: ["install", "-y", "openssh-client"]
    id: Install SSH
    volumes:
      - name: "ssh"
        path: /root/.ssh
    args:
      - build
      - >-
        $_AR_HOSTNAME/$PROJECT_ID/cloud-run-source-deploy/$REPO_NAME/$_SERVICE_NAME:$COMMIT_SHA
      - "--builder=gcr.io/buildpacks/builder:v1"
      - "--network=cloudbuild"
      - "--path=stock_subscription/"
    id: Buildpack
    entrypoint: pack
    volumes:
      - name: "ssh"
        path: /root/.ssh
  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
    args:
      - push
      - >-
        $_AR_HOSTNAME/$PROJECT_ID/cloud-run-source-deploy/$REPO_NAME/$_SERVICE_NAME:$COMMIT_SHA
    id: Push
  - name: "gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk:slim"
    args:
      - run
      - services
      - update
      - $_SERVICE_NAME
      - "--platform=managed"
      - >-
        --image=$_AR_HOSTNAME/$PROJECT_ID/cloud-run-source-deploy/$REPO_NAME/$_SERVICE_NAME:$COMMIT_SHA
      - >-
        --labels=managed-by=gcp-cloud-build-deploy-cloud-run,commit-sha=$COMMIT_SHA,gcb-build-id=$BUILD_ID,gcb-trigger-id=$_TRIGGER_ID
      - "--region=$_DEPLOY_REGION"
      - "--quiet"
    id: Deploy
    entrypoint: gcloud
    volumes:
      - name: "ssh"
        path: /root/.ssh
images:
  - >-
    $_AR_HOSTNAME/$PROJECT_ID/cloud-run-source-deploy/$REPO_NAME/$_SERVICE_NAME:$COMMIT_SHA
options:
  substitutionOption: ALLOW_LOOSE
  logging: CLOUD_LOGGING_ONLY

However, when I execute the script, I encounter the following error:
npm error code 128
npm error An unknown git error occurred
npm error command git --no-replace-objects ls-remote ssh://git@github.com/my-username/my-private-lib-repo.git
npm error ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=accept-new: 1: ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=accept-new: ssh: not found
npm error fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

It seems that the gcr.io/k8s-skaffold/pack build does not support SSH.
I’ve already validated that the SSH key is valid by installing it on a new VM and confirmed it works in Cloud Build with the following step:
- name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/git"
  entrypoint: "/bin/sh"
  args:
    - -c
    - |
      ssh -T git@github.com
  id: Check SSH Key
  volumes:
    - name: "ssh"
      path: /root/.ssh

How can I resolve this issue and successfully deploy my project?
Thanks!
